# Order By UNION in Doctrine 2

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, sql-order-by, union

I want to display the 10 last elements viewed.

Here is my query in SQL :

```
SELECT compte.dateConsultation AS dateObjet, societe.nom FROM compte, societe WHERE compte.idSociete = societe.id

UNION

SELECT opportunite.dateConsultation as dateObjet, opportunite.nom
FROM opportunite

UNION

SELECT contact.dateConsultation as dateObjet, CONCAT(CONCAT(personne.nom, " "),personne.prenom)
FROM contact, personne
WHERE contact.idPersonne = personne.id

UNION

SELECT piste.dateConsultation as dateObjet, CONCAT(CONCAT(personne.nom, " "),personne.prenom)
FROM piste, personne
WHERE piste.idPersonne = personne.id

UNION

SELECT tache.dateConsultation as dateObjet, tache.objet
FROM tache

UNION

SELECT evenement.dateConsultation as dateObjet, evenement.objet
FROM evenement

ORDER BY dateObjet DESC
```

I know that UNION is not supported in Doctrine. But I need to select all elements and do an orderBy dateConsultation on the result.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM (Your query here -- without the order by) ORDER BY dateObjet DESC`